# Objective C dictionary not returning same number

Tags: objective-c

I think I'm overlooking something but can someone see what I'm doing wrong? Why is it returning 2030774160?

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSDictionary* observation = [json objectForKey:@"observation"];
NSDictionary* imperial = [observation objectForKey:@"imperial"];
NSLog(@"value of a is : %@ !\n", [imperial objectForKey:@"temp"]);

self.forecastText.text =[observation objectForKey:@"phrase_22char"];
self.hi = [imperial objectForKey:@"temp_max_24hour"];
self.forecastHigh.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.hi];

NSLog(@"value of a is : %@ !\n", self.hi);
NSLog(@"value of a is : %@ !\n", self.forecastHigh.text);
```

---

```
2019-01-06 11:20:15.246 TiP_Clock[2205:63494] ssssy.
2019-01-06 11:20:15.465 TiP_Clock[2205:63535] Data has loaded successfully.
2019-01-06 11:20:15.466 TiP_Clock[2205:63494] value of a is : 51 !
2019-01-06 11:20:15.466 TiP_Clock[2205:63494] value of a is : 58 !
2019-01-06 11:20:15.466 TiP_Clock[2205:63494] value of a is : 2030774160 !
```

Comment: Hard to tell, show us the response data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
self.hi = [imperial objectForKey:@"temp_max_24hour"];
```

This makes `self.hi` (a pointer to) an `NSNumber`.

```
self.forecastHigh.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.hi];
```

This makes `self.forecastHigh.text` the integer-interpretation of a pointer to an `NSNumber`, which is some semi-random integer.

What you probably meant here, given the other code, was:

```
self.forecastHigh.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.hi];
```

Though it might be more clear as the equivalent:

```
self.forecastHigh.text = self.hi.stringValue;
```